# OpenGL ES GL_DEPTH_TEST Performance issue

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, galaxy-nexus

I'm writing an OpenGL ES 2.0 game in C++ running on multiple (mobile) platforms.
On IOS,Android,.. basically everything runs fine, except one device:

The computation for one frame in a specific scene take about 8ms on an HTC Desire.
Another device, a Samsung Galaxy Nexus, which is much newer takes 18-20ms.

I digged into the problem and found out that it is related to enable/disable of GL_DEPTH_TEST.

- if I comment out all glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)/glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) calls the time needed for one frame drops to 1-2ms on the Nexus.
- so I optimized the glEnable()/glDisable() calls to occur only when absolutely needed. I have 3d and 2d parts in my scene and therefore need to render 2d without depth_test and 3d with depth test.
- currently I enable depth test, draw 3d, disable depth test, draw 2d
- but still the computation takes 18-20ms on the nexus
- I also checked if the depth buffer is cleared more than needed. But it is just cleared at the start of the frame.

Is it possible that the switch of the depth test takes that much time?

Does anyone have other ideas what can be checked?

**UPDATE**

I found out that the 3d object I render is somehow responsible for the slow computation.

- If I remove the 3d object the performance is good
- but the same 3d object is used in another scene without causing such trouble
- and the weirdest thing: the Nexus runs Android 4.2 and it has an option in the developer options to visualize the cpu load as an overlay. If I enable this setting and start the game, the computation time is 5-6ms instead of 18-20ms. How can this be related?

Comment: Do you have a lot of overdraw? On some hardware, fragment shader execution is delayed until the pixel is sure to be visible, so overdraw is less expensive. On others, the fragment shader will run for every pixel you draw, whether it's later overwritten or not. I'm not sure which platforms do it which way though; maybe someone else will chime in with details.

Comment: I don't think overdrawing is a problem. I tested different things and found out that the 3d object is causing the problem somehow. I'll update my question...

Comment: Are you updating the object each frame? Is the object using a complex shader? Is the object relaying on that that needs to be processed? We need more info to be able to guess something. But it looks like is a very specific problem to your setup...